# There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier android-x86

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have tried running a release build for my .NET MAUI application now for a few days but I am not able to. The build works fine for a Debug configuration but it keeps throwing the following error message when I try to build.
There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-x86'

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: How do you publish your app? `android-x86` is not a valid runtime specifier, because Android doesn't run on x86 CPUs.

Comment: I merely try to build and deploy it to my android device through the Release configuration. I also don't know why it is trying to point to android-x86.

Comment: Can [this case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/974223/runtime-pack-for-microsoftaspnetcoreapp-available.html) which had the similar problem help you?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the resolution to my problem. I had two nuget packages installed on a class library referenced by the MAUI application that caused the issue.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer - This isn't at all compatible with a .NET MAUI application
Newtonsoft.Json - This is in the process of being deprecated. I replaced it with System.Text

Once I removed the packages and resolved the errors from the packages being removed the .NET MAUI application built correctly and I was able to create an Android APK file.

Answer (score 0):

My MAUI app project was referencing a ClassLibrary project. Removing the reference solved the problem.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76230153/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).